# Setting Image in ListView based on criteria

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I'm doing a budgeting module. 
I will like to ask that how to set the GridViewColumn to display out my desired image based on the value which I retrieve from database which are "income" & "expenses". I know how to retrieve the value from the database & display in the lisview but my question for today is that I will like to have some condition which is when found "income" will populate with income image then found expense will populate with another image???

Can this be possible. Hope to receive reply as soon as possible. Thank you.

I will provide my codes for better refer:
XAML file:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CategoriesType">
        <Border BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" Margin="-6,-2,-6,-2">
            <StackPanel Margin="6,2,6,2">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CategoriesType}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="MyItemContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <!--<EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />-->
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<ListView Height="320" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,154,0,0" Name="CategoriesListView" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="316" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource MyItemContainerStyle}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>

            <GridViewColumn Header="Types" Width="40"  CellTemplate="{DynamicResource CategoriesType}"/>

        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an image tag in the tamplate and use a converter to return the correct image based on the string value (untested code)

xaml:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
     <Converters:TypeToImageConverter x:Key="typeToImageConverter" />
 </UserControl.Resources>

 <StackPanel Margin="6,2,6,2">  
  <Image Source="{Binding Path=CategoriesType,Converter={StaticResource typeToImageConverter}"/>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CategoriesType}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

TypeToImageConverter.cs:

```
public class TypeToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
       public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
           throw ...

        var str = value.ToString();

        if (str == "income")
           return new BitmapImage(...);

        if (str = "expenses")
           return new BitmapImage(...);

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi~I'm quite new to WPF & may I ask that how to implement your codes in my solution? Do I need to create user control or customer user code for it? And how to create converter for it?

Comment: I get you point & do some research for it...
I face another problem which is setting image as I already got the value but cannot set the image....

 if (str == "income")
                    return new BitmapImage(new Uri("/images/add.png", UriKind.Relative));

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my answer which is the format of the string. Which causing me to unavailable to retrieve the image with few hours of troubleshooting & debugging. I finally found out the solution :)

I solve it by like this:In my converter.cs

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {

string str = (string)value;
string newString = str.TrimEnd();//Newly added compared with the old version

if (newString == "income")
   return new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/add.png"));

if (newString == "Expenses")
{
    //return new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/HouseWivesSavior;component/images/add.png"));
    return new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/edit.png"));
}

return null;
}
```

From referring the above that you can see that I added this code: "string newString = str.TrimEnd();"

Is because I don't want extra white space at the end of the string. As during insert into the database that my code is look like this:

```
  if (IncomeButton.IsChecked == true) {
                    CategoryType = IncomeButton.Content.ToString();
                }else{
                    CategoryType = ExpensesButton.Content.ToString();
                }
```

During runtime, I found out that why the value look strange in the format of "Expenses " instead of "Expenses"... Therefore I tried with trim of the end part see how & Bingo. I got it working like a charm.

I refered this video to out that how to trace the value: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=evO3_xutDYI

Thank you all guys for answering my question & sorry for wasting your time & effort to solve my question :) Good luck to all of you & have a nice day.